# Using Python to read through a directory of JSON files and run a reversing Python script on each file

Tags: python, json, reverse, for-in-loop, os.walk

I have a folder called Userss with ~100 individual JSON files. Each JSON file holds data about a user in the format:

```
{"cX": 298, "cY": 492, "time": 1420209750422, "y": 492, "x": 298, "type": "mousemove", "name": "Anthony Coleman"}
{"cX": 653, "cY": 57, "time": 1420209753241, "y": 57, "x": 653, "type": "mousemove", "name": "Anthony Coleman"}
{"cX": 646, "cY": 53, "time": 1420209753244, "y": 53, "x": 646, "type": "mousemove", "name": "Anthony Coleman"}
{"cX": 640, "cY": 50, "time": 1420209753250, "y": 50, "x": 640, "type": "mousemove", "name": "Anthony Coleman"}
```

(all names are made up)

Most of the files are pretty large, so doing this manually is not an option.

I am trying to reverse the content of these individual files and write this reversed data to a new 'reversed file' so that the above JSON snippet would appear as

```
{"cX": 640, "cY": 50, "time": 1420209753250, "y": 50, "x": 640, "type": "mousemove", "name": "Anthony Coleman"}
{"cX": 646, "cY": 53, "time": 1420209753244, "y": 53, "x": 646, "type": "mousemove", "name": "Anthony Coleman"}
{"cX": 653, "cY": 57, "time": 1420209753241, "y": 57, "x": 653, "type": "mousemove", "name": "Anthony Coleman"}
{"cX": 298, "cY": 492, "time": 1420209750422, "y": 492, "x": 298, "type": "mousemove", "name": "Anthony Coleman"}
```

in a new file, essentially reverse sorting them by the Unix timestamp.

The Userss file is of the format

> firstname-secondname1.json
>
> firstname-secondname2.json
>
> firstname-secondname3.json
>
> ...

FYP is the folder in which the script (test.py) to run is saved and Userss is the folder in which the user data is saved. Userss is a sub-folder of FYP.

My approach is to use `os.walk()` on the Userss directory and carry out a reversing script which I have come up with on each file. My problem is actually iterating through the directory and reading the files in, in the first place.

The following code is what I have:

## test.py

```
import os
from operator import itemgetter, attrgetter, methodcaller
import json

rootdir = './Userss'

fileHandles = {}
count = 0
totalfilelines = 0
filenum = 0
lastName=None
handle=None

for files in os.walk(rootdir):
    #print files
    #print "---------"
    #print len(files)
    #for file in files:
    filenum += 1

    with open(files) as infile:
        #for line in sortedpython(infile, key=itemgetter(2), reverse=True):
        for line in infile:
        '''
        reversing script here
        '''
```

The commented lines are where I have just tried some different things, I chose to leave them in to give an idea of my approach.

Running this gives me the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "test.py", line 37, in
>   
>       with open(files) as infile: TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, tuple found

From my understanding of what I'm trying to do, `os.walk()` should walk through the Userss directory, and as it 'walks over' each user file I'm trying to pass each of these files to the `with open()` method to open it so that I can do some work on it.

Where am I going wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## reversing a single file

```
with open(newFile,"wb") as f:
     f.write("\n".join(reversed(list(open("oldFile.txt","rb"))))
```

I guess?

## iterating over files

`os.walk` returns a tuple of the `current_directory,directories_in_cwd,files_in_cwd` not just the file path ... and the individual files are only the **filename** it is not the path to the file (either absolute nor relative)

```
for curent_directory,directories,files in os.walk(rootdir):
     for file in files:
         filePath = os.path.join(current_directory,file)
         with open(filePath,"rb") as oldFile: 
              ....
```

alternatively its probably easier to do

```
import glob
for filePath in glob.glob("/path/to/*.json"):
    with open(filePath,"rb") as oldFile:
         #do something i guess? ...
```

maybe addresses your question... although really **this is more about debugging your program.**  adding a simple `print(file)` would have shown you that what you were expecting `os.walk` to return was not actually what you were getting back from `os.walk` ... actually it looks like you did, but then commented it out... why did you think that giving a list to `open` was the correct thing to do

Comment: Maybe a subtle question is - _is reversing the same as sorting by the timestamp_ - in OP's scenario?

Comment: The reversing isn't the problem for me at the minute, I think I have a way to do that. I can't try it out until I can actually read the files though, so that's my issue.